# What is the difference between JDBC API and PostgreSQL Driver?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am creating a new Spring Boot project (https://start.spring.io/), and I am not understanding the different dependencies provided for interfacing with relational databases.

The point of confusion is "JDBC API" and "PostgresSQL Driver". My app needs to connect to a PostgreSQL database. So, which of the following are true?

1. JDBC API can be used to connect and operate with any relational (SQL) database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.), and PostgresSQL Driver **is not needed** for JDBC API to work.
2. **Both** JDBC API and PostgresSQL Driver are needed for an application to connect to a PostgreSQL database.
3. The dependency PostgresSQL Driver includes JDBC API.

I have already googled about this, but there are only manuals of how to use them.

Comment: Select Postgres, it will bring along the other components you need.

Comment: The JDBC is a set of interfaces which described the mechanisms by which you code can interact with compliant implementations.  The Postgres SQL Driver is an implementation of the JDBC interfaces which allows you to connect to the Postgres database

Comment: When selecting your dependencies from start.spring.io, your Option 2 is correct.  You need both the specification of the API (JDBC) and the implementation of the API (PostgreSQL driver) as dependencies within your project.

Comment: @jonrsharpe From what I learnt in the other answers, I need both dependencies. Selecting "PostgresSQL Driver" doesn't automatically add "JDBC API" (I just tested it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JDBC defines an API to connect and work with relational databases. The PostgreSQL driver is an implementation of this API for the PostgreSQL database.

You cannot use the JDBC API without an underlying driver to implement it. You could, however, use the driver directly, but drivers usually have very little guarantees about the stability of their APIs (other than what's promised by JDBC, of course), so it would probably be a poor idea.

Comment: If I want to use another way to connect to the db (an ORM or a SQL frameworks like jOOQ), I still need the "PostgresSQL Driver" dependency, right?

Comment: @Rick yes, at lest during runtime